# Java Heap Space error in eclipse after importing generated stub

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, crm

I generated a Stub using axis2 from command prompt.

Then i copied the stub to src folder.

When the project is refreshed in eclipse, it gives a pop up with error as `Background Indexer Crash Recovery Java Heap Space` and then again a pop up is displayed with error as `Internal Error` and asks to exit the workbench.

I have downloaded the `Account.wsdl` from Oracle CRM On demand account and the generated stub is of Account.wsdl file.

The generated stub is of 185MB. Clearly is is running `out of memory space`, but i want to connect and access the crm on demand web service.

Please let me know if there is any solution to this problem. I am using windows 7 machine with 4gb RAM.

I also increased `MaxMemorySize` in the eclipse.ini file to 600M. (Maximum possible on my system)

Comment: Increase the heap space. Why is 600M the limit?

Comment: Beyond 600M, eclipse won't start. "Can not start JVM" is the error.

Comment: What is the exact error? The only case I can think of is, you have less than 600M of free memory. Close other programs and recheck.

Comment: "Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine",is the error. Parameters in eclipse.ini are; -Xmx600m works Xmx700m does not work